# Periodic function and greatest integral function

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, periodic-functions

$\left[x+ 1/2\right] + \left[x-1/2\right] + 2\left[-x\right]$.

I have to prove that this is a periodic function, and find it's period.

Note [.] Represents greatest integer function(GIF for short).

I tried solving it by making a graph and found out that the it was a periodic function with period 1.

But is there any other approach which uses the properties of GIF like when we have find period of, for example, $\sin 4x$, we divide the time period i.e., $2π$ by $4$.

Answer (score 1):

### $$f(x) = \left\lfloor x + 1/2 \right\rfloor + 
         \left\lfloor x - 1/2 \right\rfloor + 
        2\left\lfloor -x \right\rfloor$$

First, let's compute $f(x+T)$, assuming that $T$ is an integer.

\begin{align}
   f(x + T) 
   &= \left\lfloor (x+T) + 1/2 \right\rfloor + 
      \left\lfloor (x+T) - 1/2 \right\rfloor + 
      2\left\lfloor -(x+T) \right\rfloor\\
   &= \left\lfloor x + 1/2 + T \right\rfloor + 
         \left\lfloor x - 1/2 + T \right\rfloor + 
        2\left\lfloor -x - T \right\rfloor \\
   &= \left\lfloor x + 1/2\right\rfloor + T + 
         \left\lfloor x - 1/2 \right\rfloor + T +
        2(\left\lfloor -x \right\rfloor - T) \\
   &= \left\lfloor x + 1/2\right\rfloor + 
         \left\lfloor x - 1/2 \right\rfloor +
        2\left\lfloor -x \right\rfloor \\
   &= f(x)
\end{align}

In particular, $f(x+1) = f(x)$.

It's not too much work, now, to show that, for $0 \lt x \lt 1$,

$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
-3 & \text{If $0 \lt x \lt \frac 12$} \\
-1 & \text{If $\frac 12 \le x \lt 1$} \\
\end{cases}$

So the period of $f(x)$ is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes .

> Blockquote

If we use the properties of GIF :

> Blockquote

x=[x]+{x}

and [-x]=-[x]-1   (where x is not an integer)

> Blockquote

We will be getting;

> Blockquote

[x+ 1/2] + [x-1/2] + 2[-x]

> Blockquote

=(x+ 1/2) -{x+ 1/2} + (x-1/2)-{x-1/2} + 2(-x+{x}-1)

> Blockquote

= -2 + {x+ 1/2}-{x - 1/2} + 2{x}
Proceeding in this manner using the properties of GIF will too result in the period coming out to be 1.
Hope that helps!!

Comment: Can you pls elaborate that how can we say from the last equation that the period is 1.

Comment: @Mayank Sure..Let me take your own example to explain it to you. If we need to calculate the period of sin4x, we divide 2π/4 whereas the priod of sinx-4 is still 2π.If we proceed in the similar way as the coefficient of x is 1 we can conclude that the period is one. Another quick alternative by observation is that we take any any two real numbers that differ by 1;For eg. (3.457 and 4.457) their fractional part will be same(i.e. 0.457) and the function will return the same value.In this way too, we can conclude that the function is periodic and the period is one .Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

When there are many functions , and we have to find the period of the whole function , we find the LCM(Least common factor ) of the periods of the functions.

As all the three terms are GIF functions , they all have periods 1.

Therefore , LCM of periods is also , 1.

Comment: But how can we say that lcm method can be used in gif . For example , [x] + [ x +2] , finding the lcm here will result in period being 1 but the function itself isnt a periodic function . Pls correct me if i an wrong

Comment: LCM works IF THE FUNCTION IS PERIODIC .

Comment: But how can we conclude that this function is periodic